# CSS table styles

Tags: html, css

CSS is my weak side and now I'm trying to improve it, can you please help me to spot what's the problem is, moreover which css style I'm missing.
[image: I need to make table like in top picture]

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style=width:"177px; height:92px"><img src="logo.png"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"><img src="img2.png"></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=width:"177px; height:100px"><img src="img1.png"></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that I was doing HTML email so  solved my issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: please explain the issue..

Comment: It also doesn't look much like tabular data to me. You may solve this with another markup as well. Or is this for a newsletter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you just need to make the table default CellSpacing and CellPadding 0 (assuming the top picture in your post is the desired result)

```
 <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 >
```

Although DIV's may be easier

```
<div>
  <div style = width:"177px; height:92px; float:left;">
       <img src="logo.png"><br />
       <img src="img2.png">
  </div>
  <div style=width:"177px; height:100px; float:left;">
      <img src="img1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, let's take it 1 step further

```
<style>
.wrapper
{
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:5px;
}
.content
{
    width:177px; 
    height:100px; /*Made them both 100px although one was 92px, this may not be correct*/
    float:left;
}
</style>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
       <img src="logo.png"><br />
       <img src="img2.png">
  </div><!--/content-->
  <div class="content">
      <img src="img1.png">
  </div><!--/content-->
</div><!--/wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for may be `border-spacing`, E.G. `border-spacing: 0;` ([other table specific CSS properties](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/tableproperties)) however you may wish to consult this topic first: [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation about table HTML layout, but today I need exactly to do in this layout for HTML email.

Comment: @Edvin Antonov Ahh, you may want to add that to your question. With emails, yeah, go crazy with the table layout!

Comment: Yeah, I absolutely forgot about that, but anyway thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

**css**

```
  table {border:1px solid #ccc; 
 .logo{ width:100px; }.img2{ width:300px }
```

**HTML**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="logo">
     <img src="logo.png" /><br />
     <img src="img1.png">
    </td>
    <td class="img2"><img src="img2.png"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

height is the problem. Decrease the height of logo.png image.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than answer.